# How do i get to Know which HTML table Column Drop-down is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table which is consist of drop down inside There are Three columns which have drop down which are `JAYANAGAR`,`MALLESHWARAM` and `KOLAR`
What i want to achieve is that i want to know which columns drop-down is clicked and according to that i want to show another table in `div` tag on the same page  i am finding very hard to achieve that

here is my code

```
<div id="tbl"></div>

<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="test1.html" class="link1">report1</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="Link2">report2</a></li>
</ul>

$(window).load(function() {
    $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
    $(".actionButton").click(function() {
      //get row ID

      //move dropdown menu
      $(this).after($dropdown);
      //update links

      $(this).dropdown();
    });
  });

data= [{"amount":78609,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"},{"amount":4460,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS ARAKERE"},{"amount":14513,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS AYYAPPA NGR"},{"amount":19269,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Bellandur"},{"amount":23936,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS BAGMANE CBP"},{"amount":7925,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Doddanekkundi"},{"amount":10935,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS SIDDAPURA"},{"amount":14288,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS ECITY"},{"amount":14231,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS VYDEHI"},{"amount":9090,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Hennur Main Road"},{"amount":26899,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS KADUBEESANAHALLI"},{"amount":20630,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS COFFEE BOARD"},{"amount":3250,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Kaggadasapura"},{"amount":3480,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Koramangala"},{"amount":8057,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS KASAVANAHALLI"},{"amount":13635,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Marathahalli 1"},{"amount":10000,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef bakers Marathahalli 2"},{"amount":18014,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Mahadevapura"},{"amount":11165,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS BEL LAYOUT"},{"amount":13788,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS MG ROAD"},{"amount":44735,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS MANYATA TECH PARK"},{"amount":9921,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS NAGAWARA"},{"amount":16065,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS PRESTIGE SHANTHINIKETAN"},{"amount":25445,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS PRITECH"},{"amount":10533,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS RR NAGAR"},{"amount":22390,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Kadugodi"},{"amount":11715,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS SARJAPURA ROAD"},{"amount":5075,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS SINGASANDRA"},{"amount":8730,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS SPICE GARDEN"},{"amount":26165,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"Chef Bakers Whitefield"},{"amount":26175,"billdate":"2018-08-14","outlet":"CHEF BAKERS YELAHANKA"}]

     let formatData = function (data) {

                    let billdates = [];
                    let outlets = [];
                    data.forEach(element => {
                        if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                            billdates.push(element.billdate);
                        }
                        if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                            outlets.push(element.outlet);
                        }
                    });
                    return {
                        data: data,
                        billdates: billdates,
                        outlets: outlets,

                    };
                };



                let renderTable = function (data) {
                    billdates = data.billdates;
                    outlets = data.outlets;
                    data = data.data;
                    let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
                    let table = document.createElement("table");
                    let thead = document.createElement("thead");
                    let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    let th = document.createElement("th");
                    th.innerHTML = "Bill___Date";
                     th.classList.add("text-center");
                    headerRow.appendChild(th);
                    let grandTotal = 0;
                    let outletWiseTotal = {};
                    th = document.createElement("th");
                    th.innerHTML = "Total";
                    th.classList.add("text-center");
                    headerRow.appendChild(th);

                    outlets.forEach(element => {
                        th = document.createElement("th");
                        th.innerHTML = element;
                        th.classList.add("text-center");
                        headerRow.appendChild(th);
                        outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
                        data.forEach(el => {
                            if (el.outlet == element) {
                                outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                            }
                        });
                        grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
                    });


                    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                    headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    th = document.createElement("th");
                    th.innerHTML = "Total";
                   th.classList.add("text-center");

                    headerRow.appendChild(th);

                    outlets.forEach(element => {
                        th = document.createElement("th");
                        th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
                         th.classList.add("text-right");   //ol totals
                        headerRow.appendChild(th);
                    });
                  /*  th = document.createElement("th");
                  a = document.createElement("a");
                  // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                  th.classList.add("text-center");
                  th.classList.add("dropdown");
                  a.classList.add("btn-default");
                  a.classList.add("actionButton");


                  // added
                  a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                  a.innerHTML = "Action drop";
                  th.appendChild(a); // added

                  headerRow.appendChild(th); */
                    th = document.createElement("th");
                    th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
                      th.classList.add("text-right");  // grand total
              /*  console.log(grandTotal);*/
                   // headerRow.appendChild(th);
                headerRow.insertBefore(th , headerRow.children[1] );
                    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                    table.appendChild(thead);

                    let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");


                    billdates.forEach(element => {
                        let row = document.createElement("tr");  
                        td = document.createElement("td");
                        td.innerHTML = element;
                        row.appendChild(td);
                        let total = 0;
                        outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                            let el = 0;
                            data.forEach(d => {
                                if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                                    total += parseInt(d.amount);
                                    el = d.amount;
                                }
                            });
                           /*  td = document.createElement("td");
                            td.innerHTML = el; */



                           td = document.createElement("td");
                          a = document.createElement("a");
                          // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                          td.classList.add("text-right");
                          td.classList.add("dropdown");
                          a.classList.add("btn-default");
                          a.classList.add("actionButton");


                          // added
                          a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                          a.innerHTML = el;
                          td.appendChild(a); // added

                          row.appendChild(td);



                             /* td.classList.add("text-right"); //oldata
                            row.appendChild(td); */
                        });
                        /*console.log("row is : " , row.children )*/
                        td = document.createElement("td");
                        td.innerHTML = total;
                         td.classList.add("text-right"); //column total
                       // row.appendChild(td);
                        row.insertBefore(td , row.children[1] );
                        tbody.appendChild(row);

                    });

                    table.appendChild(tbody);

                    tbl.innerHTML = "";
                    tbl.appendChild(table);
                    table.classList.add("table");
                    table.classList.add("table-striped");
                    table.classList.add("table-bordered");
                   table.classList.add("table-hover");
                }
                 let formatedData = formatData(data);
                 renderTable(formatedData);
```

If `JAYANAGAR` dropdown is clicked then how would i know it's jayanagar dropdown and have to show the data which is for jayanagar in next table

and also all my Outlets like jayanagar malleshwaram are dynamic it can vary on the basis of user input

[Here is the fiddle link of my HTML table with drop down](http://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/xkt9501m/6/)
please anyone out there help me out

Comment: you need to add some javascript for that , each need to have seprate value.So that you can check later.

Comment: sorry i update my comment , i meant value

Comment: you need to give that dropdown Id and u can easily take the value of that dropdown which value is selected

Comment: @ZZA can you help me with the fiddle link please

Comment: @viveksingh, you should have something to identify. And on the basis of that identification, you can add an if/else condition and achieve your results. Also look for click target property ( it might make it more simple :) )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript check here

Comment: @Aslam any link  with respect to my code updation wil be helpfull...i have to call a another table also onthe click of dropdown

Comment: @ZZA i only want to know the header so that i can use that value in my query to create a new HTML table

Comment: that can also be accomplish easily u need to use jquery hide and show.

Comment: @ZZA yup i know about hide and show..can you help me with some  code where i am clicking  `JAYANAGAR` a diff content is called if i am selecting `MALLESHWARAM`  dropdown then different content is called ?

Comment: sorry what u want to do is to take value of selected one or what? a little confuse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184613/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-zza).

Answer (score 0):

You can get `td` clicked when you click combo inside td like this

```
 var clickedtd = -1; 

 $(window).load(function() {

    $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
    $(".actionButton").click(function() {
    clickedtd = $(this).parent().index(); // get clicked td index
     console.log($(this).parent().index());

      //move dropdown menu
      $(this).after($dropdown);
      //update links

      $(this).dropdown();
    });



    $(".link1").click(function(){
    console.log("Report 1 : ");
   if(clickedtd == 2){
    // report 1 JAYANAGAR clicked
  console.log("JAYANAGAR");
   } else if(clickedtd == 3){
    // report 1 MALLESHWARAM clicked
  console.log("MALLESHWARAM");
   }else if(clickedtd == 4){
    // report 1 KOLAR clicked
  console.log("KOLAR");
   }

});


// Report 2 click event
$(".Link2").click(function(){
console.log("2: "+clickedtd);
   if(clickedtd == 2){
    // report 2 JAYANAGAR clicked
   } else if(clickedtd == 3){
    // report 2 MALLESHWARAM clicked
   }else if(clickedtd == 4){
    // report 2 KOLAR clicked
   }

});


  });
```

Now when you have `clickedtd` you know which td you clicked now in report click you can check that `clickedtd` to show the appropriate report.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkt9501m/25/)

See the console for log

**Edit 1:**

This should be enough to get you started and complete the flow.

To get header dynamically by index

```
var headerName = $('.table-hover').find('th').eq(clickedtd).text(); 
console.log("headerName: "+headerName);
```

Check console of Report 1 click

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkt9501m/26/)

Comment: hey you are right but i have to do this dynamically here i have only there outlets i.e jayanagar,malleshwaram,kolar..but user can selects 10-15 then how would i know howmuch condition i have to run

Comment: wait let me check please don't go any where

Comment: hey check my code i have updated the json here but its not giving me the header name no  check this link [http://jsfiddle.net/xkt9501m/26/]

Comment: Pls, check my Updated Fiddle added in the answer. It's working you can get help from there

Comment: there you are using if else condition with jayanagar malleshwaram index but i don't have fixed index these may increased

Comment: Dude focus on this line    var headerName = $('.table-hover').find('th').eq(clickedtd).text();  Forget about if else ..   this will give you any th name based on index its not hardcoded.

Comment: but why are you using `.eq(clicked).text` this one is only giving for 3 of jayanagar,malleshwaram.kolar

Comment: My dear Vivek, lets say you have 100 th . So on click of any td you need its th. To do that you need the clickedIndex.
This is called getting dynamic header name, 
Still if you have doubt. God bless you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184620/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-mytwocents).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can bind `click` on `tr`, and use the `e.target` and `this` respectively get the `a` and `tr`, like this:

`document.querySelector("tr").addEventListener("click",function(e){console.log(e.target,this)})`